# Cisco ASA LDAP Group Privilege Level

Tags: cisco, ldap, cisco-asa, radius, aaa

We have a pair of ASA 5510s (8.4.3) on which we use LDAP authentication for VPN and SSH access.  On all of our Catalyst switches, which use RADIUS, we're able to set the shell:priv-lvl to 15 in the RADIUS config (2008R2 NPS).  However, the best I can find on the ASAs, including in all the Cisco docs, is to abuse some other field, such as title or company, by sticking "15" into it and mapping that to the Privilege-Level RADIUS attribute in the AAA config.  What I really want to do is assign anyone in an AD group L15 privs on the ASAs without having to type in a shared password.  Anyone know if there's a way to do this?

Comment: At first read, you want to eliminate the enable password? Is that right? If not, please clarify. I'm unsure what you mean by "shared password".

Comment: Can you clarify your question, please? As it's written now, I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: Have you considered using TACACS instead of LDAP? TACACS will allow you to restrict level 15 membership to AD security group, provides AD integrated authentication, and does not require you to edit fields in AD.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not mind using LDAP you can do exactly what you need without changing anything on the server infrastructure.

The way that we do ASA LDAP integration is to us the memberOf LDAP attribute to trigger a match on the value we want to edit. For cli AAA you can configure the following attribute map:

```
ldap attribute-map NetworkAdministrators
    map-name  memberOf IETF-Radius-Service-Type
    map-value memberOf "CN=NetAdmins,OU=Security,DC=mycompany,DC=local" 6
```

This sets the service-type to 6 (admin) for any users that log in and match that group. Next define a new AAA Server Group to use just for device administration, you do not want to break your attribute-maps for vpn users.

```
aaa-server networkers-auth protocol ldap
```

Now create a server entry for your LDAP server, this can be to the same server that you use for VPN or other LDAP functions.

```
aaa-server networkers-auth (inside_interface) host 10.1.1.1
    ldap-base-dn DC=netgain,DC=local
    ldap-scope subtree
    ldap-naming-attribute sAMAccountName
    ldap-login-password *****
    ldap-login-dn cn=asa2ldap,cn=users,DC=mycompany,DC=local
    server-type microsoft
    ldap-attribute-map NetworkAdministrators
```

The last line `ldap-attribute-map NetworkAdministrators` is what associates the ldap-map to your authentication server.

Finally lets bring all the work together and apply it to the ASA AAA section:

```
aaa authentication ssh console networkers-auth LOCAL
aaa authentication enable console networkers-auth LOCAL
aaa authorization exec authentication-server
```

So to test you can no ssh to your ASA and user your LDAP user, you should then be able to get logged in without issue. Now when you enter `enable` mode you will get prompted for a password. You will then use your unique LDAP password for authentication.

Please test this completely on your equipment, because if improperly configured on your ASA could let any LDAP user admin privileges on your ASA.